# Screen flickering with Webstorm autocomplete popup

Tags: 16.04, drivers, flicker

I have Ubuntu 16.04.1 fully updated.

Sometimes when in Webstorm the autocomplete popup is shown the monitor that has WebStorm flickers for a couple of seconds every time I press a key on the keyboard, making impossible to digit something. I have to change application and wait some minutes before I can use Webstorm again.

I haven't seen the problem  with other programs

```
uname -a   
Linux *** 4.8.0-040800-generic #201610022031 SMP Mon Oct 3 00:32:57 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Graphic card: *Intel® Iris Pro Graphics 580 (Skylake GT4e)*

Comment: Did you perform basic checks like - reinstalling the app ? Also do you have any graphic card ?

Comment: whats your gpu? there are some gpu specific tweaks to prevent screen tearing.

Comment: @SirajusSalekin I have an  *Intel® Iris Pro Graphics 580 (Skylake GT4e)*. Also I noticed it happens more (but not only) on the monitor attached with a minidisplay port (I already tried to use another cable), and a bit less on the hdmi one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these steps

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel-tearfree.conf
```

Paste

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
  Driver      "intel"
  Option      "TearFree"     "true"
EndSection
```

Save, and reboot.

This fixed the screen flickering issue on a Sandy Bridge i5. It might help you too.

If you want, you can revert the changes whenever you want by typing

```
sudo rm /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel-tearfree.conf
```

Comment: Nope, now it fails to login, the error is `Feb 20 08:57:22 *** kernel: [   38.995158] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* too many voltage retries, give up
Feb 20 08:57:22 *** kernel: [   39.077060] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* too many full retries, give up`

Comment: You can remove the file anytime following the last command. But before you do so, try removing these two lines `Option      "AccelMethod"  "sna"` and `Option      "TripleBuffer" "true"`, if still does not work remove it using `sudo rm /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel-tearfree.conf`. Finally, you can do  a little research on [Oibaf](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers) optimized.

Comment: This, and install `linux-generic-hwe-16.04`, improves a lot the situation! Thanks :)

Please edit your answer to remove the two "wrong" options, I want to share the reply with some colleagues!

Comment: @rpadovani, I'm glad it worked. Updated the answer, thanks for your cooperation :)